# How to pass Maven (Nexus) credentials to build.gradle file in various situations?

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Gradle v3.4.1 (old, but that's another topic) on Mac OS Catalina (in my case).

We're using a Nexus repo for builds and I have my creds defined in my `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` file. The following `build.gradle` syntax works for our Bitbucket pipeline and Jenkins runs. I store creds in my Bitbucket repo, and in Jenkins credentials plugin.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "$ZIFT_MAVEN"
        credentials {
            username System.getenv("NEXUS_USR")
            password System.getenv("NEXUS_PSW")
        }
    }
}
```

and I do

```
$ ./gradlew clean build -x test -PNEXUS_USR=*** -PNEXUS_PSW=***
```

Contrary to popular claims, "It does NOT work on my machine!" LOL.

This does work on my local machine however, but does NOT work in Jenkins nor Bitbucket pipelines.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "$ZIFT_MAVEN"
        credentials {
            username "$NEXUS_USR"
            password "$NEXUS_PSW"
        }
    }
}
```

and I simply do

```
$ ./gradlew clean build -x test
```

What is the ONE way that works for all situations - local, Jenkins, Bitbucket pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
maven {
    url "$ZIFT_MAVEN"
    credentials {
        username (System.getenv("NEXUS_USR") != null ? System.getenv("NEXUS_USR") : "$NEXUS_USR")
        password (System.getenv("NEXUS_PSW") != null ? System.getenv("NEXUS_PSW") : "$NEXUS_PSW")
    }
}
```